# SQL INSERT INTO for specific cell

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use this to insert the value "yes" into the list_title column where stream_number='3'. I can't figure out why it won't actually insert "yes" into the cell or any cell at all for that.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO livestreams (list_title) VALUE ('yes') WHERE stream_number='3'");
```

Heres the SQL i'm using to create the table if this helps

```
$createTable = "CREATE TABLE livestreams (stream_number INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(stream_number), stream_name CHAR(30), desired_username CHAR(30), stream_status CHAR(10), channel_description VARCHAR(300), game_name VARCHAR(100), viewer_count INT, list_title CHAR(30))";
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. An `INSERT` adds new rows, while `UPDATE` changes something within existing rows.

```
UPDATE livestreams SET list_title = 'yes' WHERE stream_number = '3'
```

That SQL query should do.

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT` inserts a new *row* into the table.
To *update* an existing *row*, use an `UPDATE` query.

Apparently you need to stop thinking in terms of Excel "cells". Databases work with *rows* a.k.a. *records*, and these records have *fields*. The datastore is not a 2D grid where you "insert" data into "cells"; even though it is often presented like that in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `INSERT INTO` with `WHERE`. Use `UPDATE` instead.